# Environment variables with daemon

Tags: perl, dependencies, export, daemon

I'm currently trying to set up properly a daemon to run a task on a remote machine. The thing is, I can launch the command manually properly, but when it's launched by the daemon, it won't work because the environment variables haven't been set up.

Before using my command manually, I have to do this:

```
sudo -s 
export HOME=/home/tim
cd ~
export PERL5LIB=/usr/local/my/lib
export PATH=/my/path/to/tools/bin
```

And then I run my command. So I suspect it won't work if the daemon hasn't set up this. How can I do that with the daemon or get rid of the dependencies?

Maybe with a temporary folder? Not sure.

Comment: Change `cmd` to `bash -c cmd` (assuming those env vars are set by the `.bash_profile`).

Comment: That's a very restricted PATH; no access to `/bin` or `/usr/bin` is a little unusual.  Are you sure that's what you intended.  Also, the `export HOME = /home/tim` line is not good; there shouldn't be spaces around the `=` sign.

Comment: yes you re right, there's no space. I ve just added them by mistake when I wrote "manually" the line and yes the path is leading to some /bin folder

Comment: Why are you deleting the post? It is a good question (seen and available in revisions, under the link at "_edited [time]_"), which may be useful to other people, as good votes confirm. I suggest that you restore it and leave it be.

Answer (score 2):

The [`%ENV`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables) allows access to and manipulation of environment variables. See [Environment in perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#ENVIRONMENT). (There is also a core module [Env](http://perldoc.perl.org/Env.html) for convenience.) With it we can say `print $ENV{HOME}`, or add environment variables by setting new hash keys, or change (write new) values for its existing ones. This environment is inherited by processes started by the program.

So with the parent

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;

$ENV{VAR}      = '...';  # HOME, PATH, ... or a new variable
$ENV{PERL5LIB} = '...';  # where some modules are installed

system("script.pl");
```

the program `script.pl` that is called

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;
use SomeModule qw(func);  # SomeModule is installed in path in PERL5LIB

print "$ENV{VAR}\n";
func();
```

can use `$ENV{VAR}` and can directly `use` modules installed in the path set up for `PERL5LIB`.

This affects only processes that your program starts. It doesn't change the environment for its parent (which a daemon won't have anyway), and has no effect on things independent of your program.

I'd like to add – make sure that you have a proper daemon running. See, for example, [Complete Dissociation of Child from Parent in perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Complete-Dissociation-of-Child-from-Parent). You can also see [in perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Handling-the-SIGHUP-Signal-in-Daemons) 
how to utilize `SIGHUP`.

Comment: @Alex I edited the answer by splitting worded explanation into code sample

Comment: Thank you, it helped ! But one last thing, I installed a package bundle on my system which allows me to run a command like this:  "bundle /my/path [some options]"  So I've told my daemon to use this "bundle" command, however it tells me that it cannot find the command "bundle".. Do you have an idea what could go wrong?

Comment: @Alex  When you run from the shell, the `bundle` is found in some standard path defined in your shell configuration. From the script, you can run `bundle` so that it involves the shell -- then you can make use the `PATH`, but if shell is bypassed it won't. In a script I like to specify full paths to programs to run, so `/path/to/bundle/bundle ...`.